# Tkinter python 3 - gpg encryption

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a function that uses gpg -c to encrypt a file via a entry box in tkinter. My issue is that gpg -c prompts the user to enter a password twice through terminal.

I am able to execute the command but it requires input through terminal. Is it possible to use a variable or some placeholder that I can combine with the command? That way terminal is not required. Or are there any alternatives?

For example here is the normal command line:

```
gpg -c test.txt
Enter passphrase: ***********    
Repeat passphrase: ***********
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the gpg commandline tool, it would be better to use the python-gnupg library found here:[https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/)  where encrypting and signing would look something like this (airlifted from the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#using-signing-and-encryption-together)):

```
>>> encrypted_data = gpg.encrypt(data, recipients, sign=signer_fingerprint, passphrase=signer_passphrase)
```

This would avoid two things:

<strike>1. Having an external dependency to the gpg binary (makes distribution difficult)</strike>

1. Dealing with command-line inputs and outputs which is tricky

Comment: Both python-gnupg and gnupg are wrappers for the command line binary via subprocess. I suggest redoing this answer by way of [the official GPGME bindings](https://dev.gnupg.org/source/gpgme/browse/master/lang/python/). BTW, they're well documented and you ought to find an example of [exactly this in the repo](https://dev.gnupg.org/source/gpgme/browse/master/lang/python/examples/howto/symcrypt-file.py).